# How to get coordinates from google map in iOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps, gps

I am doing a iOS application for Golf with features like GPS tracking,scoring system,etc.

In this application, I need to provide more golf courses with details like hazards coordinates, pin and fairway coordinates.

What is the best method to obtain this information?

Comment: SO is about helping solve specific programming problems, and not writing complete solutions, or providing help/guidance to designing your program.  This question is probably going to get closed.

Comment: But assume the body of your question is what you are asking, you can either go measure it yourself (like the SkyCaddie golf GPS's), or you can manually measure the obstacles in Google Earth, or you can ask other users to mark points on a map in your program.  It's not easy (or cheap) to create a good Golf GPS program or there would be many more good ones on the market

Comment: Ya .ok.thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting some links here which include detail explanation about Using the Google Places API With MapKit and also include the sample code.

Link 1: [Using the Google Places API With MapKit](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13160/using-the-google-places-api-with-mapkit)

Link 2: [Introduction to MapKit on iOS Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2847/introduction-to-mapkit-on-ios-tutorial)

Hope this will help you.